# C#. Как правильно переписать LINQ запрос?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<bubbles> bubbles = new List<bubbles>();
bubbles.Add(new bubbles { Title = "red" });
bubbles.Add(new bubbles { Title = "green" });
bubbles.Add(new bubbles { Title = "red green" });
bubbles.Add(new bubbles { Title = "red red" });
bubbles.Add(new bubbles { Title = "red green black" });
bubbles.Add(new bubbles { Title = "123" });

List<string> str = new List<string>() { "green", "123" };

foreach (var r in bubbles.Where(x => str.Contains(x.Title)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Title);
}
```

Есть такой кусок кода, где проверяется что `bubbles.Title` содержит любое значение из `str`, но вместо всех строк содержащих `"red"` и `"123"` - он выводит только полное совпадение строки(т.е. не `"red green black"` как задумывалось, а просто `"red"`), в результате чего выводится лишь два значения, а не 5

Я так понял, что при сравнении двух листов через `Contains` - он работает немного иначе, чем при поиске конкретного значения в листе? Как можно переписать запрос чтобы он находил все `bubbles` содержащие `123` или `red`?

Comment: содержащие `123` или `red`?

Comment: @Igor да, чтобы он находил не только первое и последнее значение из List<bubbles> (т.к. они полностью схожи), а так же и остальные, содержащие в себе эти слова

Comment: Что-то типа такого: `bubbles.Where(x => str.Any(y => x.Title.Contains(y)))`

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо! Это действительно то что нужно

Comment: Но на будущее старайтесь приводить весь нужный для запуска код (если его не 100500 строк). А то пришлось самому класс `bubbles` писать, благо, там три строчки. )  И зря вы назвали класс с маленькой буквы, и переменную назвали также, как класс. Это запутывает.

Comment: @CrazyElf просто прошелся поиском и заменой и поменял ошибочное название(Bubles на bubbles), не заметил что пропала заглавная.
А так я подумал что new Bubbles { Title = "123" } будет достаточным, разве что его вручную нужно будет прописать, тут да, исправлюсь)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверил, вроде работает как нужно:

```
bubbles.Where(x => str.Any(y => x.Title.Contains(y)))
```

То есть человеческим языком: "Выбрать элементы списка `bubbles`, у которых в поле `Title` содержится хотя бы один элемент списка `str`".

Вывод:

```
green
red green
red green black
123
```